# What is a good way to internationalize an Elm application?

Tags: elm

I need to internationalize the UI strings in my ELM HTML application to 3 different languages.

I am thinking of doing this:

1) I will get the currentLanguage from Javascript, and pass it down in the ProgramWithFlags. I'llkeep the language in the model

2) I'll setup some types in my code

```
type alias Languages = English | French | Spanish
-- One of these for each string I want to internationalize
type alias InternationalizedStrings = StringHello | StringFoo | StringBar
```

3) I'll make a function for returning each translated phrase to use in my Views.

```
getPhrase: InternationalizationString Languages -> string
getPhrase stringId lang = 
   case lang of
      English ->
           case stringId of
              StringHello -> "Hello"
              StringFoo -> "Foo"
              StringBar -> "Bar"
      French ->
           case stringId of
              StringHello -> "Bonjour"
              StringFoo -> "Oui"
              StringBar -> "Non"
      ...
```

Is there a better way to do this? I have lots of string.

Comment: What you could maybe do is serve a certain model type based on the language code in the URL. For example, `/fr/phrase` would serve frenchModel

Comment: One advantage to using union types is that each tag can have parameters. You could have a `StringHello String` tag that indicates you need to specify the user name, and it's strongly typed in a way that normal dictionary lookups cannot be.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want compiler errors when you don't provide the translation for a string your solution is on the right track.

If you want to either allow yet untranslated strings or find it tedious to have a type for every translatable string, you might want to switch to a `Dict`-based solution. to tinker with it, just throw it into http://elm-lang.org/try:

```
import Dict exposing (Dict)
import Html exposing (text)


type Language
    = English
    | French
    | Spanish


type alias Key =
    String


main =
    text <| translate French "Hello"


translate : Language -> Key -> String
translate lang key =
    let
        dict =
            case lang of
                English ->
                    Dict.fromList
                        [ ( "Hello", "in english" )
                        ]

                French ->
                    Dict.fromList
                        [ ( "Hello", "salut" )
                        ]

                Spanish ->
                    Dict.fromList
                        [ ( "Hello", "hola" )
                        , ( "someKeyThatOnlyExistsInSpanish", "42" )
                        ]
    in
        Dict.get key dict |> Maybe.withDefault ("can not find translation for " ++ key)
```

Answer (score 2):

A while ago, I had a crack at internationalisation, and came up with the following setup:

- define the language in a global `model`
- have a very simple function, to be used in `view` modules and functions
- the function has a signature of `localString : Language -> String -> String`
- `localString` basically does a lookup in a global dictionary to find a translation from the word you provide to the language you provide.
- it will always give back a `String`, defaulting to the original word, if it cannot find the word you provide, or if it cannot find the translation to the language you provide.
- keep the global dictionary (and helper) functions NOT in the model, but in a separate file (it is pretty static data, which won't change in runtime).
- the `Language` type is a Union Type, to ensure we only have 'approved' languages.
- the actual dictionary uses conversions to string. The `Dict` type does not allow strong types as the key.

That way, using internationalisation has minimal impact on the rest of the code:

- You need to add a `Language` to your `Model` (which you could get through JS port)
- You can still use short and readable code in your views to translate, like

  `p [] [ text <| localString model.language "car" ]`
- All hardcoded strings in your own code remain in one simple default language, to keep the rest of your code readable.

Here is the gist of what I was working on, you can copy/ paste to [elm-lang.org/try](http://elm-lang.org/try) (not fully tested functionally or performance-wise with large numbers of strings and translations)

```
import Html exposing (div, p, text)
import Dict exposing (Dict)

-- Manage your languages below

type Language = English | Spanish | French

defaultLanguage : Language
defaultLanguage = English

languageToKey : Language -> LanguageKey
languageToKey language =
  case language of
    English -> "English"
    Spanish -> "Spanish"
    French -> "French"

keyToLanguage : LanguageKey -> Language
keyToLanguage key =
  case key of
    "English" -> English
    "Spanish"-> Spanish
    "French" -> French
    _ -> defaultLanguage

english : LocalWord -> (Language, LocalWord)
english word =
  (English, word)

spanish : LocalWord -> (Language, LocalWord)
spanish word =
  (Spanish, word)

french : LocalWord -> (Language, LocalWord)
french word =
  (French, word)

-- Internal stuff

type alias Word = String
type alias LocalWord = String
type alias LanguageKey = String

type alias Dictionary = Dict Word WordDict
type alias WordDict = Dict LanguageKey LocalWord

init : Dictionary
init =
  Dict.fromList []

newLocalWord : Word -> (Language, LocalWord) -> Maybe WordDict -> Maybe WordDict
newLocalWord word (localLanguage, localWord) wordDict =
  wordDict
  |> Maybe.withDefault (Dict.fromList [])
  |> Dict.insert (languageToKey defaultLanguage) word
  |> Dict.insert (languageToKey localLanguage) localWord
  |> Just

addTranslation : Word -> (Language, LocalWord) -> Dictionary -> Dictionary
addTranslation word newTranslation dictionary =
  dictionary
  |> Dict.update word (newLocalWord word newTranslation)

localString : Language -> Word -> LocalWord
localString language word =
  let
    wordEntry =
      Dict.get word globalDictionary
    localLanguage =
      languageToKey language
  in
    case wordEntry of
      Just wordDict ->
        Dict.get localLanguage wordDict
        |> Maybe.withDefault word

      Nothing ->
        word

add : Word -> List (Language, LocalWord) -> Dictionary -> Dictionary
add word translationList dictionary =
  List.foldl (addTranslation word) dictionary translationList

-- BUILD DICTIONARY BELOW

globalDictionary : Dictionary
globalDictionary =
  init
  |> add "Hello" [ spanish "Hola", french "Bonjour" ]
  |> add "Man" [ spanish "Hombre", french "Homme" ]
  |> add "Child" [ french "Enfant" ]


-- For Elm-lang Try only
localModel = 
  { language = Spanish }

main =
  div []
    [ p [] 
      [ text <| "Hello in Spanish: " 
      ++ localString localModel.language "Hello" 
      ]
    , p [] 
      [ text <| "In dictionary, but not in Spanish: " 
      ++ localString localModel.language "Child" 
      ]
    , p [] 
      [ text <| "Is not in dictionary: "
      ++ localString localModel.language "Car" 
      ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [blog post about this](https://toast.al/posts/2016-08-20-seer-stones-translations-using-unions-in-elm.html) a couple months ago. If you have the ability, try to prefer using ADTs over `Dict`s since `Dict`s can't give you the same guarantees at a type level (which is why `Dict.get` returns `Maybe a`). ADTs can also have the data type you're acting on type checked as well `MyPhrase Int String` that you can pattern match on and use whatever `toString` method you'd like (e.g. `MyPhrase foo bar -> "My phrase contains " ++ toString foo ++ " & " ++ bar ++ "."`). That being said, existing systems/translation services might make it difficult to use this method without writing a parser from `.elm` to `.json` or `.po`.